# Random variable $X$ has uniform distribution on set {$2,3,4,5,7,8,11$}. What's the probability of $p(4\leq X \leq 7)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Random variable $X$ has uniform distribution on set {${2,3,4,5,7,8,11}$}.

What's the probability of $p(4\leq X\leq 7)$?

From lecture I know that formula for uniform distribution is:
$$P(X=i)=\frac{1}{n},i=1,2,...,n$$

so will $i$ be number of elements $i= 1,2,3,4,5,6,7$ or actual value of those elements $i=2,3,4,5,7,8,1$

as for $p(4\leq X\leqslant \leq 7)$, does this mean that I have to calculate $P(X=4),P(X=5),P(X=7)$?

If so whats the probability they ask me for?
Sum of 3 numbers above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$P(X=4)=P(X=5)=P(X=7)=\frac{1}{7}$$

thus the requested probability is

$$\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{7}=\frac{3}{7}$$

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. Thanks for confirming

Comment: It is problems like these that make mathSE such an interesting place.

Comment: @wolfies : maybe not intersting for someody but surely helpful for others